# using EJB from within an applet

Tags: java, applet, ejb

I have been trying to inject/use my EJB from within an applet without success.  I have created a new Java EE Enterprise application. I am using glassfish 3 & netbeans 7.1

The main problem has been instantiating `InitialContext`.

Here are the declarations of my beans.

```
   @Stateless
   public class UserFacade implements UserFacadeLocal {
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MetroEntitiesPU")
   private EntityManager em;

   @Remote
   public interface UserFacadeLocal {
```

I have been able to create a stand alone Java client by including the `gf-client.jar` class-path and using the following code.

```
try {
   UserFacadeLocal ufl = (UserFacadeLocal) new InitialContext()
     .lookup("bidd.data.ejb.UserFacadeLocal");
   System.out.println("FROM EJB COUNT: " + String.valueOf(ufl.count()));
} catch (NamingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication3.class.getName())
      .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The problem is when i am trying to do the same in the applet. The applet is compiled in a jar file and then loaded from a jsp website which is part of my enterprise application in netbeans.

This is the line in the init method that gives the error that follows.

```
UserFacadeLocal ufl = (UserFacadeLocal) new InitialContext()
  .lookup("bidd.data.ejb.UserFacadeLocal");
```

### Error

```
Need to specify class name in environment or system property, 
  or as an applet parameter, 
  or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: *"I have been able to create a stand alone java client"*  1) It would be easier to launch that from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS would also provides a better end-user experience. 2) It is 'Java', not 'java'. 3) Don't include noise like 'Thanks' or sigs. like 'Terence'.  For the latter, edit [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1358278/user1358278).  And as an aside, 'Terence' is a lot nicer, and easier to remember, than 'user1358278'. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Need to specify class name in environment or system property, 
  or as an applet parameter, 
  or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

- `environment or system property`
    Not practical for a publicly deployed applet<sup>1</sup>.
- `as an applet parameter`  
  Should be trivial<sup>1</sup>.  Something like:
  `<applet ..><param name='the.name' value='bidd.data.ejb.UserFacadeLocal'>
  </applet>`
- `in an application resource file`
  Might be workable, but presumably you need to add a `param` to identify the file.

---

1. applet: The same applies to JWS apps., which is what I actually recommend for this deployment.